# Compare DateTime Fields in a Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, datetime, data-types

I'm helping our Events team with a new flow that we're building. Within the flow, we're attempting to compare two DateTime fields with one another in order to execute actions based on the difference between the two DateTime fields.

For example, we have the following objects and fields:

**Attendee Object - Registration Date/Time**

**Event Object - Event Start Date/Time**

There are four scenarios we want to cover:

1. If Event Start Date/Time is more than 48 hours from Registration Date/Time
2. If Event Start Date/Time is less than 48 hours from the Registration Date/Time, but more than 24 hours from the Registration Date/Time
3. If Event Start Date/Time is less than 24 hours from the Registration Date/Time, but greater than 1 hour from the Registration Date/Time
4. If Event Start Date/Time is less than 1 hour from the Registration Date/Time

In each scenario, we are creating "Scheduled Email" records in order to send out what we're calling Pre-Event Reminders, effectively triggering email communications to folks 48 hours, 24 hours, or 1 hour prior to the Event Start Date/Time in order to remind them of the upcoming event.

I am having difficulty creating the appropriate formulas to handle this calculation as I continue to run into the following error no matter how many times I've revised the formula:

**The formula expression is invalid: Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, received Text**

I've tried using multiple DataTypes to no avail (Boolean, Date/Time, Number, even Text), but cannot seem to figure this out.

One such formula we've tried of type Boolean is as follows:

IF(
{!$Record.conference360__Registration_DateTime__c} <
({!$Record.conference360__Event__r.conference360__Event_Start_Date_Time__c} -2),
TRUE,
FALSE)

How can I compare these two Date/Time fields in order to determine if scenarios 1, 2, 3, or 4 are TRUE, so that we can then execute downstream actions accordingly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using formula fields, Flow formula variable(s), or ??? Could you just have comparisons of the `DateTime` fields in a Decision element to determine which route to take? Decision elements process from top down and take the first Outcome that matches.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?